# Weird rails error "permission denied: bin/rails" for old rails apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, oh-my-zsh

I'm getting this error whenever I run `rails` (or any  rails command)

`_rails_command:2: permission denied: bin/rails`

ONLY when i'm inside some **old** rails app directory.

In these directories `bundle exec rails c` command works but `rails` or even `rails -v` don't work.

**Background:**
I keep my coding workspace in dropbox folder.
Now I recently installed Manjaro and hence all the rails apps which I downloaded back from my previous OS I call them **old** rails app.

**In Short:**
Rails works fine everywhere except for old rails apps.
`bundle exec rails c` works fine though.
Ruby versions which I've tried:
`2.0.0 (rvm), 2.1.1(rvm), 2.1.1 (system)`

**Gem Environment :**

`RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2014-02-24 patchlevel 451) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/tat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@latest
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/tat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/tat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@latest/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/tat/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/tat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@latest
     - /home/tat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/tat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@latest/bin
     - /home/tat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/bin
     - /home/tat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin
     - /home/tat/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /usr/bin/core_perl
     - /home/tat/.rvm/bin`

**UPDATE**:
Its working fine in bash, the problem seem to be with oh-my-zsh.

Here is my rvm-info (from zsh):

```
ruby-2.0.0-p451@latest:

  system:
    uname:       "Linux tat-box 3.10.37-1-MANJARO #1 SMP Mon Apr 14 20:56:29 UTC 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
    system:      "manjaro/0.8.9/x86_64"
    bash:        "/usr/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.3.8(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:         "/usr/bin/zsh => zsh 5.0.5 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.25.23 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "21 hours 33 minutes 15 seconds ago"
    path:         "/home/tat/.rvm"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "2.0.0p451"
    date:         "2014-02-24"
    platform:     "x86_64-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2014-02-24 revision 45167"
    full_version: "ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [x86_64-linux]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/home/tat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@latest"
    ruby:         "/home/tat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/home/tat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/home/tat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/home/tat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/home/tat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@latest/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/home/tat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@latest/bin:/home/tat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/bin:/home/tat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/bin:/home/tat/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/core_perl:/home/tat/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/bin:/home/tat/.rvm/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/home/tat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@latest"
    GEM_PATH:     "/home/tat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@latest:/home/tat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/home/tat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451"
    IRBRC:        "/home/tat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       "latest"
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In the directory you mentioned is your rails in executable mode. If not you can apply

```
chmod u+x bin/rails
```

and make it executable.

Comment: yep that works :). But when I use bash it works regardless of chmod'ing.

Comment: This fixes the problem as a workaround, but the it's the answer by @newtron54 that should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 12):

So what worked for me, anyone coming across this issue is to run

```
bundle exec rake app:update:bin
```

You'll be given a prompt asking if you want to overwrite? The options here are:

- Y - yes (default one, just press Enter for it)
- n - no (leave current file without changes)
- a - all (apply all changes)
- q - quit
- d - diff
- h - help

I chose a and it seemed to work ok.

Answer (score 9):

Run

```
bundle exec rake rails:update:bin
```

It will update bin/rails and bin/rake files.

Answer (score 2):

I have this when I try to use a rails 4.0 version.
So when I try to put `bundle exec` first, like:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

or

```
bundle exec rails s
```

work's.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and here's what helped me.
Open *~/.zshrc* and add this

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was:

```
bundle exec rake rails:update:bin
```

**or just use:**

For new rails versions:

```
 bundle exec rake app:update:bin
```

For old rails versions:

```
bundle exec rake rails:update:bin
```